# Spatio-temporal kriging

Tags: interpolation, kriging, spatio-temporal-data

I have a geospatial dataset of air quality and I want to interpolate the air quality value across time and space for unmeasured location and time instace.
I found [gstat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/gstat.pdf) package in R could do the spatio-temporal kriging.
However, the implementation is not very efficient. For example, [this article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/spatio-temporal-kriging-in-r/) mentioned that it took him one day to handle the data of two days (his dataset has ~6500 datapoints, I tried the code on my laptop and it seems to run forever).

Is there any packages (Python, R) which can handle data spatio-temporally and efficiently? I have a big dataset of ~20K datapoints (each datapoint has coordinates, timestamp and Z value - the air quality value). 
The second question is: I know that I could use 3D kriging in PyKrige considering the time axis as the 3rd dimension. Is this a reasonable use? Any scientific reference for this use?